pgAdmin 4 server version - "Access Denied"
When trying to export server definitions (or backup any tables from within a schema) from a SERVER installation of pgAdmin (installed on Redhat Linux), I get an "Access Denied" error :
Error message
Menu options to export servers
I am expecting this to work, as I have tried the following :

Through "Storage Manager" I was able to able to upload new files into this same directory and am also able to create subdirectories without any issue.
If I login to the OS as the apache user (after changing the nologin status) I am to export tables into this directory using pg_dump from the command line without any issue.
I can't seem to find any log files that provide more info ?

Given the first 2 observations above, I do not believe this is genuinely a permissions issue, it seems to be something wrong with the pgAdmin tool ?

You must specify a directory in which the server (the user on whose behalf it is started) has write rights

The "/" in the image tranlsates to this directory at the os level : /var/lib/pgadmin/storage//. The subdirectory "datadumps" is present in this same directory, and even if try to write it into this subdirectory, it fails with the same error :       drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 6 Sep 23 09:45 datadumps

so you can't tell where you're going wrong. the message is clear - you do not have write rights to the corresponding directory. it seems that the user you are using is apache. and I don't see a connection between it (it uses apache web servers) and pgAdmin. the presence of 777 rights indicates that you are looking at a different directory (if the path is correct, the server may be running in a chroot container).

Correct, I can't tell where I am going wrong. I do agree that the message is clear, but it makes no sense. I am pretty convinced that I am in the correct directory structure. When I "browse" in the tool, I can see all the directories and subdirectories (including the one that has 777 privs) and still it won't allow me to create the file.

check which user is actually being used. then check the permissions of all directories on the path to the target directory. refrain from 777 as rights

Thanks for the assistance. 777 should not be used - agreed, however, out of desparation,  I have made the all subdirectories in the path, all the way from root (/), 777, and still I get the "Access Denied" :-(.

give the output of these three commands: netstat -tapn | grep 5050, ps -aux | grep python and namei -l /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/<username>/

add one -Z to the ps and namei parameters to see the security context, if one is set

netstat -tapn | grep 5050 provides no results. Nothing is listening on 5050

system_u:system_r:tuned_t:s0    root       999  0.0  0.3 404164 28672 ?        Ssl  Oct01   0:06 /usr/libexec/platform-python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 root 1001 0.0  0.6 935712 52712 ?    Ssl  Oct01   0:33 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/goferd --foreground
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 3859 0.0  0.0 12112 1088 pts/0 S+ 08:47   0:00 grep --color=auto python
system_u:system_r:rhsmcertd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 22355 0.0  0.6 374080 51152 ? S   Oct01   0:00 /usr/libexec/platform-python /usr/libexec/rhsmd

f: /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/
dr-xr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   var
drwxr-xr-x root   root   lib
drwxrwxrwx apache apache pgadmin
drwxrwxrwx apache apache storage
drwxrwxrwx apache apache 

It would be really handy if there were log files that captured this error, or an option in pgAdmin to configure destination directories ?

There is a security context set, which means that you are using SELinux, which is where the restriction comes from. The easiest solution is to switch the system to work in permissive mode. But in doing so, you give up the protection that SELinux provides.

To configure the security context correctly, you must give the output of ps -auxZ | grep python and namei -lZ /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/<username>/ . Put the data in your post so that it is properly formatted

system_u:system_r:tuned_t:s0    root       999  0.0  0.3 404164 28672 ?        Ssl  Oct01   0:08 /usr/libexec/platform-python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P

system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 root 1001 0.0  0.6 935712 52712 ?    Ssl  Oct01   0:42 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/goferd --foreground
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 9671 0.0  0.0 12112 976 pts/1 S+ 14:42   0:00 grep --color=auto python

system_u:system_r:rhsmcertd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 22355 0.0  0.6 374080 51152 ? S   Oct01   0:00 /usr/libexec/platform-python /usr/libexec/rhsmd

The above are the 3 lines output from ps -auxZ | grep python

I don't have a -Z option for namei       :   namei: invalid option -- 'Z'
Try 'namei --help' for more information.

It looks like permissive mod i already enabled on the system ? This is from the /etc/selinux/config file :

This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

> It looks like permissive mod i already enabled on the system? yes, but that's just the configuration file. To see what mode the system is running in, it is best to use the sestatus command

To properly configure selinux, one must see what security context the server is running with. Basically, pgadmin has a built-in server that by default works on port 5050, but you obviously don't use it (perhaps you run it as an apache module - which explains the username you mentioned above). To see the security context use ps -auxZ | grep apache

Next, you need to check the security context of the target directory /var/lib/pgadmin/storage//. if namei doesn't have a -Z parameter for you, just use ls -laZ /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/ but it's nice to see all the directories up to /. Remember that selinux requires valid DAC access rights and only then checks the security context

if the problem is in selinux, you can view its logs /var/log/audit/audit.log

Thanks mr mcwolf. I am not convinced this is selinux related. sestatus command suggests everything is "permissive" AND, I did a "tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log" while I attempted the export, and nothing appeared in the log file.

nothing else, the system first checks the DAC rights. After that, if it uses selinux (enabled and in enforcing mode), restrictions are imposed based on the specified security context. in permissive mode, the security context is checked, but no restrictions are enforced (only a record is made in the log files). The only other explanation (I didn't see a well-formatted output of what I was looking for, just your claim that everything is fine) is that some kind of container (chroot, docker...) is being used.

Hi Everyone, I appear to have resolved my own issue (thanks to mr mcwolf for all the assistance). It turns out all I needed to do was to create a config_local.py file under /usr/pgadmin4/web. The contents of this file is as below (it is possible to add multiple of them). Once the service has been restarted, these entries  appear as an option in the "storage manager" in pgadmin, and I have no problems writing to them !

SHARED_STORAGE = [{
'name': 'Shared-Storage1',
'path': '/var/lib/pgadmin/storage//',
'restricted_access': False
}]
